# Html symbol not recognised

Tags: java, android

I have a variable with text inside that contains html tags. I want to strip these out. I have tried to use:

```
Html.escapeHtml(variable)
```

But I am getting an error of

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Html'

Firstly, is this the correct approach to stripping the tags out, and secondly, what is causing this error? Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't declared the variable.

Comment: It is only available API 16 and higher?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne I'm using this as an example, of course I've declared the variable previously.

Comment: @alpinescrambler I'm using API 19.

Comment: Check your imports, should be android.text.Html, and maybe check you mindSDK value as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the package from the android.text.Html

Reference Link : [Click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)

Right now, we have multiple methods in the open source with the same escapeHtml. Look for the right import.

Comment: What do you mean by "we have multiple methods in the open source" ?

Comment: I mean to say, just they were other projects having the same method(For Example: org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils has the same method like andriod)